# Exporting t-SNE visualization Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a possibility to export the tensorboard visualizations of tensorflow with the labels?
Like the t-SNE as a 2d picture or 3d standalone.
Other possibilities like websolutions I might not know of are welcome as well